# Список видео с SD card GridView

Tags: java, android

Выдает ошибку, уже все перепробывал. Permission включил.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    GridView gv;
    public ArrayList<File> files;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gv.setAdapter( new GridAdapter());
        String internalStorage = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();

        files = getListFiles(new File(internalStorage));
    }

    class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return files.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return files.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_grid,parent,false);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()));

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
        ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
            } else {
                if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp4")) {
                    inFiles.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
        return inFiles;
    }
}
```

Comment: Стэктрейс прикрепите, пожалуйста.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.hp.myapplication, PID: 10013
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hp.myapplication/com.example.hp.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridView

Answer (score 2):

У вас в ошибке написано:

`android.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridView`

По всей видимости ваш `R.id.gridView` не `GridView`, а `GridLayout`.

Comment: Да действиетельно , глупай  ошибка . Я исправил , но приложение все равно выдает ошибку.

Comment: Какую теперь ошибку выдает приложение?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.hp.myapplication, PID: 27808
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hp.myapplication/com.example.hp.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                  at com.example.hp.myapplication.MainActivity$GridAdapter.getCount(MainActivity.java:41)
                                                                                  at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:187)
                                                                                  at com.example.hp.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)

Comment: @guess поищите по SO на тему NullPointerException. Ответ по этому вопросу уже есть на ресурсе.